# How does Array indexing work?

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone explain `array[++index]` vs `array[index++]`?

I am reading a data structure book and it seems like this notation does have a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **array[++index]** - increment to variable index in current statement itself.
> **array[index++]** - increment to variable index after executing current statement.

Answer (score 6):

`array[++index]` will first add 1 to the variable `index`, and then gives you the value;
`array[index++]` will give you the value at `index`, and then increment `index`.

Answer (score 1):

`++index` will increment index by 1 **before** it's used.  So, if index = 0, then `arry[++index]` is the same as `arry[1]`.

`index++` will increment index by 1 **after** it's used.  So, if index = 0, then `arry[index++]` is the same as `arry[0]`.  After this, index will be 1.

Answer (score 1):

The different behavior is not specific to arrays.

Both operators increment `index` by one.

`++index` returns `index+1` while `index++` return the original value of `index`.

Therefore when used to access an array element, the two operators will give different indices.

Answer (score 1):

let's say index is 0

`array[++index]` give you element 1 and index is 1 after that

`array[index++]` give you element 0 and index is 1 after that

Answer (score 1):

The preincrement operator (`++index`) first increments the variable and only then returns its value. So `var = array[++index]` is equivalent to:

```
index += 1;
var = array[index];
```

The postincrement operator (`index++`) first returns the value of the variable and only then increments its value. So `var = array[index++]` is equivalent to:

```
var = array[index];
index += 1;
```